# Equivalence of Brownian motion's finite dimensional distribution

Tags: stochastic-processes, normal-distribution, brownian-motion

I know the definition of a (standard) Brownian motion $\{B_t:t\geq0\}$. (i) $B_0=0$. (ii) the process has independent increments. (iii) for all $t,s\geq0$, $B_{t+s}-B_s$ are normally distributed with expectation zero and variance $s$. (iv) almost surely, $t\mapsto B_t$ is continuous.

I confused the following question.

> Let $\{B_t:t\geq0\}$ be a Brownian motion. If $\{X_t:t\geq0\}$ have same finite-dimensional distribution as a Brownian motion, and $X(t)$ is almost surely continuous. Then, $\{X_t:t\geq0\}$ is a Brownian motion.

Why is this? Why finite-dimensional distribution equivalence derive the definion (i), (ii), (iii)?

Thank you for your cooperation.

Comment: The only thing that isn't clear is that the increments are independent (remember that the normal distribution is characterised completely by its mean and covariance). To see this, note that a family of random variables $(Y_{\alpha})_{\alpha\in A}$ is independent if and only if each finite sub-family is independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(i) Since $X_0 = B_0$ in distribution, we have $$\mathbb{P}(X_0 \in A) = \mathbb{P}(B_0 \in A) = \delta_0(A)$$ for any measurable set $A$. Hence, $X_0=0$ almost surely.

(ii) Take $0=t_0 < \ldots < t_n$. By assumption, the random vectors $U:= (X_{t_1},\ldots,X_{t_n})$ and $V:=(B_{t_1},\ldots,B_{t_n})$ have the same distribution. Since $(B_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a Brownian motion, $V$ is Gaussian, and so is $U$. If we define $$f(x_1,\ldots,x_n) := \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2-x_1 \\ \vdots \\  x_n-x_{n-1} \end{pmatrix},$$ then $$f(U) = \begin{pmatrix} X_{t_1} \\ X_{t_2} -X_{t_1} \\ \vdots \\ X_{t_n}-X_{t_{n-1}} \end{pmatrix} \quad \text{and} \quad f(V)=\begin{pmatrix} B_{t_1} \\ B_{t_2}-B_{t_1} \\ \vdots \\ B_{t_n}-B_{t_{n-1}} \end{pmatrix}$$ have the same distribution and both are Gaussian. Now recall that the entries $G_j$ of a Gaussian random vector $G=(G_1,\ldots,G_n)$ are independent iff they are uncorrelated, i.e. if the covariance matrix of $G$ is a diagonal matrix. Since the Brownian motion $(B_t)_{t \geq 0}$ has independent increments, it follows that the covariance matrix of the Gaussian random vector $f(V)$ is a diagonal matrix, and so is the covariance matrix of $f(U)$, which means that the entries $X_{t_j}-X_{t_{j-1}}$ are independent.

(iii) By assumption, $(B_s,B_{t+s})$ and $(X_s,X_{t+s})$ have the same distribution. This implies that $X_{t+s}-X_s = B_{t+s}-B_s$ in distribution, and so $X_{t+s}-X_s \sim N(0,t)$.

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused (ii) and (iii). In (ii), $(B_{t_1}, B_{t_1})$
is Gaussian? My following  idea is correct? $p(t,x):=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi
t}}e^{-x^2/2t}$. $\mathrm{P}(B_{t_1}\in
A_1,B_{t_2}-B_{t_1}\in
A_2)=\int_{A_1}dx_1\int_{A_2}dx_2p(t_1,x_1)p(t_2-t_1,x_2)$.
From this I obtain $\mathrm{P}(B_{t_1}\in A_1,B_{t_2}-B_{t_1}\in
A_2-A_1)=\int_{A_1}dx_1\int_{A_2-x_1}dx_2p(t_1,x_1)p(t_2-t_1,x_2)=
\int_{A_1}dy_1\int_{A_2}dy_2p(t_1,y_1)p(t_2-t_1,y_2-y_1)$. But L.H.S equals
$\mathrm{P}(B_{t_1}\in A_1,B_{t_2}\in A_2)$, so $(B_{t_1}, B_{t_1})$ is Gaussian. Is there a more simple thinking?

Comment: And in (iii), ''$(B_s,B_{t+s})$ and $(X_s,X_{t+s})$ have the same distribution. This implies that $X_{t+s}−X_{s}=B_{t+s}−B_s$ in distribution'' means that $\mathrm{P}(X_{t+s}-X_s\in A)=\mathrm{P}(X_s \in A_1, X_{t+s}\in A+A_1)=\mathrm{P}(B_s \in A_1, B_{t+s}\in A+ A_1)=\mathrm{P}(B_{t+s}-B_s\in A)$? Sorry for ranting.  @saz

Comment: @sate Sorry, can't really follow your comments. 1) If $U,V$ are two random vectors which are equal in distribution, then $f(U)$ and $f(V)$ are equal in distribution for any measurable function $f$. That's a general result which I used several times in my answer. E.g., if you choose $f(x,y) := y-x$ you see that $(X_1,X_2)=(Y_1,Y_2)$ in distribution implies $X_2-X_1 = Y_2-Y_1$ in distribution (which I used in (iii)).  2) I didn't mention/use anywhere in (ii) that $(B_{t_1},B_{t_1})$ is Gaussian. Note that the times $t_1<\ldots<t_n$ are strictly increasing.

Comment: Sorry, I miswrote it, and correct expression is $(B_{t_1},B_{t_2})$. And, I understand what you say.